# unknown symbol instated of inverted comma in php file

Tags: php, html

i have index.php file. in index.php file following code is there

```
<p>This is john's computer</p>
```

when i run index.php in browser it shows like following.

```
This is john�s computer
```

How to solve it ??

thanks in adv.

Comment: You probably just didn't specify the character encoding properly.Try adding this to the HTML : `<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>`

Comment: remove the single quote and then type it yourself. It might have come from a copy paste and is not supported by your encoding / charset

Comment: Try to type the whole sentence and check it.

Comment: @HankyPanky Thanks...i did it same and solve the problem.

Comment: @AnazA Thanks...i did it same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `&#39` instead of directly using

```
<p>This is john&#39;s computer</p>
```

Comment: right answer. but i do it another way. i just remove unknown character and type my self a single quote. this solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ASCII characters.

```
&#39;
```